# How to save html user input as javascript variable on next page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save user input as a Javascript variable so I can use it on other pages of my site. How can I do that? Now the variable will be deleted if I go to the next page and I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: userInput is not defined"

Here is my code:

```js
function test(){
    const userInput = document.getElementById("naam").value;
    
    window.location.href = "interactie1.html";
    console.log(userInput);
}

document.getElementById("js--terminal--text").innerHTML = "";
typeText = (textToBeTyped) =>{
        
    if(textToBeTyped != ""){
        document.getElementById("js--terminal--text").innerHTML += textToBeTyped[0];
        textToBeTyped.splice(0,1);
        setTimeout(() => {
            typeText(textToBeTyped);
        },100);
            
    }
    
}
    
typeText(Array.from("Hello this is "))
typeText(userInput);
```

```html
<input class="naam__aanwezigheid__form" type="text" id="naam" placeholder="Type je naam" required>
<button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are changing the page, the script is unloaded, therefore you can't access these variables.

Maybe you can try this : [Session storage](https://lage.us/Javascript-Pass-Variables-to-Another-Page.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20ways%20to,query%20string%20with%20the%20URL.)

Or make sure you've loaded the script in the first place to use the variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tools like React, they have the concept of states, that will allow you to hold the variable in memory, while you change the URL ( React is a single page application though ).

Otherwise, you will either need to use cookies, or have a server to hold those values for you while you change pages.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use the [JavaScript Session Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). using URL Parameters should do the trick too.

Answer (score 0):

Use localstorage for save your values.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "your value");
```

Then get saved values in next page.

```
let your_value = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: Remember to clear localstorage when done. using localstorage.removeItem("key");

Answer (score 0):

The userInput will be empty since you're loading another page.
You'd be needing a storage, you can access the browsers storage section with:

window.localStorage.setItem('userData ',  userInput);

It's stores it as a key value pair.
userData is key for retrieval.
userInput is the value that is returned.

Hence,  on loading the new page you can retrieve it using:
window.localStorage.getItem('userData');

Feel free to read more on localStorage in js.